# Delphi XE: Can I call virtual constructors with parameters from a classtype-constrained generic type without resigning to hacks?

Tags: delphi, generics, constructor, polymorphism, generic-constraints

I'm trying to build a generic ancestor for composite controls. The initial idea looked something like this:

```
type
  TCompositeControl<TControl1: TControl; TControl2: TControl> = class(TWinControl)
  private
    FControl1,
    FControl2: TControl;
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override; 
  end;

  TLabelAndEdit = TCompositeControl<TLabel, TEdit>; // simple example for illustration only

constructor TCompositeControl<TControl1,TControl2>.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  FControl1 := TControl1.Create(Self);
  FControl2 := TControl2.Create(Self);
end;
```

As you might already be aware, this will trigger compiler error E2568: Can't create new instance without CONSTRUCTOR constraint in type parameter declaration. Adding the `constructor` constraint doesn't help however as it implies a parameter-less constructor.

Casting the templates to `TControl` makes the code compilable:

```
...
FControl1 := TControl(TControl1).Create(Self);
...
```

...but it results in an Access Violation at runtime.

One hack that would probably work is invoking the constructor via RTTI, but I would consider that a rather dirty solution.

Another hack that essentially works is using class type variables as intermediates:

```
type
  TControlClass = class of TControl;

constructor TCompositeControl<TControl1,TControl2>.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
var
  lCtrlClass1,
  lCtrlClass2: TControlClass;
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  lCtrlClass1 := TControl1;
  FControl1 := lCtrlClass1.Create(Self);
  lCtrlClass2 := TControl2;
  FControl2 := lCtrlClass2.Create(Self);
end;
```

Is there a cleaner solution? Also, can somebody explain to me why the classtype-constraint does not suffice for invoking the virtual constructor on the type parameter directly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your typecast is bad: `TControl(TControl1).Create(Self)`. That tells the compiler that `TControl1` is an *instance* of `TControl`, but we know that it's not an instance. It's a class reference. Type-cast it to the class-reference type instead:

```
FControl1 := TControlClass(TControl1).Create(Self);
```

Comment: Arghl, yep. Good catch. Makes sense.

Comment: BTW, Do you also happen to know why I cannot declare `FControl1` and `FControl2` as `TControl1` and `TControl2` respectively? If I do I get a compiler error E2010 Incompatible types: 'TLabel' and 'TControl' at the end of the unit.

Comment: No idea. I don't have a version of Delphi to test. Pare down the code from this question and post it as a new question, if there's not already a question about it here.

Comment: Sure will do. The strange thing is that I haven't been able to reproduce the problem with anything simpler than `TComponent`-descendants so far... Anyway, thanks again for the original answer!

Answer (score 0):

An alternate syntax is

```
FControl1 := TControl1(TControl1.NewInstance); // get memory for object
FControl1.Create(self); // call type-specific constructor

FControl2 := TControl2(TControl2.NewInstance); // get memory for object
FControl2.Create(self); // call type-specific constructor
```

This is used in Delphi's Classes.pas::CreateComponent
I just can't decide which option is the least ugly!

Answer (score 0):

It seems it the latest delphi version (Seattle) this compiler error is not emitted anymore. I had the same issue we an application, but only when compiled with DelphiXe8 not with delphi Seattle

Answer (score -1):

If your Class uses a constructor without parameters (like TObject), I would suggest to do what the compiler says:

"Add a constructor constraint to the type-parameter declaration"

It should look something like this:

TCompositeControl < Control1: TControl, constructor; TControl2: TControl, constructor > = Class(TWinControl)

If you do so, you should be able to make the necessary call to the constructor of the generic Type.

Howether, I don't know, if it works with a constructor, who needs a parameter.

Please let us know, if it works.

Comment: Please reread the question. This is specifically about constructors *with* parameters and the `constructor` constraint cannot be used with these.